# Have Midichlorians Ever Communicated Directly With People?

Tags: star-wars

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Yoda taught Luke to clear his mind and he was able to see visions of what would happen (his friends being tortured in the cloud city).  There are other examples of people having visions of the future or what was happening through the Force.

But these are visions of events that are based on what has happened, is happening, or will happen.

Is there a case of the midichlorians communicating with anyone, perhaps by showing them visions that are clearly a message and not just images of events?

I know that the Force "controls your actions," but also "obeys your commands," so I'm not talking about just the Force controlling or guiding actions, but any scenes or situations where it's clear midichlorians, through their collective intelligence, is trying to directly communicate directly with someone.

Is there any time, either on screen or in the expanded universe, where something like this happens?

Comment: Does intercourse count as communication? I mean, don't get Shmi started on the topic ...

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. IMHO you need to define a lot clearer what you mean by "communicating" - otherwise anything from prophesy of The One to knowing "the right path to take" is communications

Comment: @DVK, that's a bit tough, since I don't want to limit it and find out that there's something I didn't know about.  Basically, it would be something other than just visions of events (like maybe a message of visions that were intended to pass on information to a person and the visions weren't just glimpses of real-world events).

Comment: @Tango - you mean visions that were NOT of a possible future?

Comment: @DVK or of past or current events.  In other words, maybe something showing Luke a story to try to say, "Darth is your Pop!" before he knew -- but not just a vision of his birth.  Or anything else - like a person being led someplace for what seemed to be no reason at all - or something else that wasn't just the Force acting through midichlorians.

Comment: Someone mentioned in a question/answer relating to Shmi that a specific book makes it obvious that the midichlorians made Anakin as a sort of reaction against Darth Plagueis.  Were the midichlorians communicating there, or was it part of the narrative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that [midi-chlorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midichlorian) cannot communicate the way you think. They are intelligent, but not in the way we know, It's more like a [Swarm intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence).

Vision is one way they have found to communicate; force sensitive can listen to them and command them. But the communication is still uncommon, there's no dialogue, it's just a question of will and concentration.

The problem of communication between species is well explored in the [*Ender's Game* series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_%28series%29). Without spoiling anything, interaction with intelligent species like the Formics and the Pequeninos is not simple when they don't think and communicate the way you do.

Comment: +1 for "intelligent spices" ... They're smart **and** delicious! (please don't edit that)

Comment: It's *creative misspelling*.